# Sliding Shape Animation in Javascript or HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, animation, shapes

I am looking to create a venn diagram where the two circles with text slide into a single one and a new bit of text appears over the single circle.

Which would be better to use, HTML5 or Javascript? Is there a tool that would make this easier?

Comment: Javascript will certainly be handy for this. Jquery always makes animations easier. While I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to accomplish, check out jquery. You will of course use this with CSS and HTML. Are you new to these technologies?

Comment: The animation can easily be done with HTML5, but changing the text becomes a little bit harder, I'd likely recommend a javascript approach